# SVN master-slave configuration on apache Testing

Tags: apache, svn, master-slave

I have two svn (master-slave configuration) setup already on apache2.2. I need to test this setup in different scenarios such as network failure.
Are there any important test cases I must consider.
What points should I keep in mind while testing.

[Updated]
We are using write through proxy at slave.
Is there any documentation/checklist available on internet I can utilize.

[Updated]
I have included SSL using self-signed certificate recently. **Is there any special test cases for SVN using SSL?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the greatest problems will occur when a failure happened during the sync.

Thus you want to add such test cases to your testing. Specifically, you will need to define what will be necessary after a failure during synchronization (repository cleanup scripts, etc.)

Other test cases I can think of:

- You may also encounter problems regarding file locking. So you may have scripts ready also for that case. You can add a test case for that to verify that your scripts are working as expected.
- You will have also to verify that you cannot commit to slave when it's out-of-sync.
- Finally you can ensure that you and your team are correctly informed if your slave run out-of-sync through an email or something.

Comment: Thanks for response.
Please read question. I have updated it.

Comment: You may find helpful information at the end of [this blog post](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/2007/10/yesterday-at-th/)

Comment: I am implementing ssl so is there any ssl specific test cases?

Comment: As your testing purpose is to validate the SVN replication process, SSL connection problems will need to be treated as any other network issue. You may use Microsoft's [Certificate Creation Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3.aspx) to test certificate problems for instance...